# npm run dev can not install webpack cli

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, npm-install, laravel-mix

I have a **laravel** application with the below config:

- **laravel version 7.30.4**
- **npm version 6.14.6**
- **node version 12.18.3**

When I want run `npm run dev`, this **question** is asked:

```bash
    CLI for webpack must be installed.
    webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
    Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no):
```

After typing `yes`, this **error** is showed:

```bash
    Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/package.json'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\SibCo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\5852\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:78:19)
    at runCli (C:\Users\SibCo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\5852\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:50:26)
    at C:\Users\SibCo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\5852\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:139:5
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\SibCo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\5852\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
     ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **updated** my npm version to **v7.11.2** and delete **node_modules** and ran :

```bash
    npm install
```

again, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing webpack globally:

```
npm install -g webpack webpack-cli
```

Comment: i install webpack but when i run ```npm run dev``` i have same question to install webpack!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `webpack-cli 4` or `webpack 5`, change `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve`.

Example:

```
"serve": "webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress"
```

**You might want also to check this comment on GitHub:**

NPM package.json scripts are a convenient and useful means to run locally installed binaries without having to be concerned about their full paths. Simply define a script as such:

**For webpack-cli 3.x:**

```
"scripts": { "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server" }
```

**For webpack-cli 4.x:**

```
"scripts": { "start:dev": "webpack serve" }
```

Comment: where should i change config?(which file?)

Comment: i run your command and when i run ```npm run dev``` i have same question to install webpack!